# Pandas - Splitting data from single row into multiple rows

Tags: pandas

I am trying to extract data from a pandas Dataframe column that has a specific pattern. I am trying to loop in such that each occurrence is created as a new row. Given below is how the data is:

```
id: id_101
description: id_name1
id: id_102
description: id_name2
id: id_103
description: id_name3
```

All of the above content is stored in a single row. I am trying to convert as below where each occurrence is made into a new row:

```
 , id, description
0, id_101, id_name1 
1, id_102, id_name2
2, id_103, id_name3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If data has always pairs first [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and then [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) with helper column created by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df = df['col'].str.split(': ', expand=True)
df['g'] = df.groupby(0)[1].cumcount()
df = df.pivot('g', 0, 1).rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
print (df)
  description      id
0    id_name1  id_101
1    id_name2  id_102
2    id_name3  id_103
```

Or get values after `:`, convert to numpy array and reshape to new `DataFrame`:

```
a = df['col'].str.split(': ').str[1].to_numpy()
df = pd.DataFrame(a.reshape(-1, 2), columns=['id','description'])
print (df)
       id description
0  id_101    id_name1
1  id_102    id_name2
2  id_103    id_name3
```